# using the "change" event properly

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an error pop up when I select the `pick up the day` option and I added it successfully but before moving on let me show you a screenshot of my app so you can understand better:
[image]

and this is the error state when I don't pick any day

[image]

my question is about when I'm in the error state and I pick a day I want the error message and the red color to get removed.

I googled that problem and I found the `change` event I think it's the solution to that problem I tried to use it but I I think I didn't use it properly so here is my code and thank you in advance.

***Note**: please execuse me if I puted my entire code because I thought maybe you need it in the testing and myproblem is in the first module (the internalController module)

**HTML**

```
  <div class="backIMg">
    <div class="headTime" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="1000">Time:
      <span class="Time"> </span></div>
    <div class="Date" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="1000">
      <span class="subDate"> %11%/%04%/%2019%</span>
    </div>
  <div class="error-case"  data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1800">
    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle error-sign">
    <span class="error-text">error</span>
    </i>
    <p class="error-description">you should pick a day</p>
  </div>


    <select class="optionList" id="optionList" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1300">
      <option class="option-item" value="pick the day" selected>Pick the day</option>
      <option class="option-item" value="Monday" >Monday</option>
      <option class="option-item" value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
      <option class="option-item" value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
      <option class="option-item" value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
      <option class="option-item" value="Friday">Friday</option>
      <option class="option-item" value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
      <option class="option-item" value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
    </select>
<div class="from-1">
  FROM :
</div>
 <input type="time" class="inputTime" data-aos="fade-down"
 data-aos-duration="1600"
     value="">

     <div class="to-1">
       TO :
     </div>
   <input type="time" class="inputTime2" data-aos="fade-down"
 data-aos-duration="1600"
     value="">

 <input type="text" class="inputText" data-aos="fade-up"
 data-aos-duration="1900"
 placeholder="             I   '   m         g   o   i   n   g          t   o       .    .   .   .">

 <div class="checkbox" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1500">
   <input class="checkboxx" type="checkbox" id="prfix" value="true"
          checked>
   <label for="huey">Add the prefix I'm goning to </label>
 </div>

<button class="add__btn  submit-1"><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i></button>

 <div class="plansBackground">
   <div class="container">
   <!-- <h1 class="day">
    Monday
   </h1>

   <div class="plan-ID" style="text-align:center">
   <i class="fas fa-calendar-check check"></i>
   <span class="line">
   <span class="from">FROM: </span><span>10:30 AM</span>
   <span class="to"> TO: </span><span class=""> 11:30 AM</span> <span class="to-do">
   I'm going to study</span>
   <i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>
   </span>
   </span>
   </div> -->
   </div><!--end of the container div-->
 </div>
  </div> 
  <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
var internalController = (function(UICtrl) {


  return {

    addItem: function(day, from, to, text, goingToCkecked) {
      var newPlan, ID, errorCase = false,selectedItem;
      if (day === 'pick the day') {
        document.querySelector(".error-case").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.querySelector(".optionList").classList.add("error-red");
        errorCase = true;
      } else  {
        document.querySelector(".error-case").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.querySelector(".optionList").classList.remove("error-red");
        console.log("that is me");
      }


selectedItem=document.querySelector(".option-item").value;
//here is the change event function
document.querySelector(".option-item").addEventListener("change",function(){
  if (errorCase==='true' && selectedItem!="pick the day") {
    document.querySelector(".error-case").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.querySelector(".optionList").classList.remove("error-red");
    console.log("I got trigered");
  }
});




        //CREATE NEW ID
        if (data[day].length > 0) {
          ID = data[day][data[day].length - 1].id + 1;
        } else {
          ID = 0;
        }
        //CREATE NEW PLAN BASED ON THE PICKED DAY

        if (day === "Monday" || "Tuesday" || "Wednesday" || "Thursday" || "Friday" || "Saturday" || "Sunday") {
          newPlan = new Plan(ID, from, to, text, goingToCkecked);
        }

  };


})(UIController);



var UIController = (function() {
  var DOMstrings = {
    inputDay: ".optionList",
    inputTimeF: ".inputTime",
    inputTimeT: ".inputTime2",
    inputText: ".inputText",
    goingToCkecked: ".checkboxx",
    inputBtn: ".add__btn",
    planContainer: ".container",
    errorCase: ".error-case",
    optionList: ".optionList",
  };


  return {
    getInput: function() {
      return {
        inputDay: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputDay).value,
        inputTimeF: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputTimeF).value,
        inputTimeT: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputTimeT).value,
        inputText: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputText).value,
        goingToCkecked: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.goingToCkecked).checked,


      };
    },
    getDOMstrings: function() {
      return DOMstrings;
    },
    addPlanList: function(obj, day) {

      var html, element;
      //CREATE HTML WITH A PLACEHOLDER TEXT
      if (day === "Monday" || "Tuesday" || "Wednesday" || "Thursday" || "Friday" || "Saturday" || "Sunday") {
        html = '<h1 class="day"> %day%</h1><div class="plan-%ID%" style="text-align:center"><i class="fas fa-calendar-check check"></i><span class="line"><span class="from">FROM: </span><span>%timef%</span><span class="to"> TO: </span><span class="">%timet%</span> <span class="to-do">I\'m going to %text%</span><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></span></span></div>';
        element = DOMstrings.planContainer;

        if (day === "pick the day") {
          return;
        }

        //REPLACE THE PLACEHOLDER TEXT WITH SOME ACTUAL DATA

        if (obj.id === 0) {
          newHtml = html.replace('%day%', day);
          newHtml = newHtml.replace('%ID%', obj.id);
          newHtml = newHtml.replace('%timef%', obj.from);
          newHtml = newHtml.replace('%timet%', obj.to);
          newHtml = newHtml.replace('%text%', obj.text);
        } else {
          newHtml = html.replace('%day%', "");
          newHtml = newHtml.replace('%ID%', obj.id);
          newHtml = newHtml.replace('%timef%', obj.from);
          newHtml = newHtml.replace('%timet%', obj.to);
          newHtml = newHtml.replace('%text%', obj.text);
        }

        //INSERT THE HTML INTO THE DOM
        document.querySelector(element).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newHtml);
      }

    }


  };



})();


var controller = (function(interCtrl, UICtrl) {
  var input, newPlan;

  function setupEventListeners() {
    var DOM = UICtrl.getDOMstrings();

    document.querySelector(DOM.inputBtn).addEventListener("click", ctrlAddPlans);

    document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        ctrlAddPlans();
      }
    });

  }

  //1.GET THE TIME

  //still empty

  //2.GET THE DATE
  document.querySelector(".subDate").innerHTML = interCtrl.date();

  var ctrlAddPlans = function() {

    //3.get the filed input data
    input = UICtrl.getInput();
    console.log(input);

    //4.add the plan to the internalController
    newPlan = interCtrl.addItem(input.inputDay, input.inputTimeF, input.inputTimeT, input.inputText, input.goingToCkecked);
    //5.add the plan to the UI
    UICtrl.addPlanList(newPlan, input.inputDay);
  };

  return {
    init: function() {
      console.log('the app has started');
      setupEventListeners();
    },

  };



})(internalController, UIController);


controller.init();



setTimeout(

  function() {
    document.querySelector(".plansBackground").classList.add("height");
  }, 1000

);
```

Comment: Where is your `hel()` function defined in the first place?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek sorry when I got frustrated I tested with it as we all know inline Js is a bad practice but it didn't work too I forget to remove it but i did now

Comment: you want to remove red color background of error message or input field?

Comment: let's suppose that when I entered I didn't pick a day so I got the select option colored with the red color and the error message shows up, so I picked a day let's suppose I picked wednesday at that moment I want the red color to be removed as well as the error message without clicking on the submit button again

Comment: I think I see a bug. You are attaching `change` event to the `option.option-item`s instead of `select#optionList`. You see, it's the `select` itself which is emitting the `change` event, not `options`. Try attaching the event to the `select` control

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a bug. You are attaching `change` event to the `option.option-item`s instead of `select#optionList`. You see, it's the `select` itself which is emitting the `change` event, not `option`s. Try attaching the event to the `select` control:

```
document.querySelector("#optionList").addEventListener("change",function(e){
  var selected = e.target.value;
  if (errorCase==='true' && selected!="pick the day") {
    document.querySelector(".error-case").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.querySelector(".optionList").classList.remove("error-red");
    console.log("I got trigered");
  }
});
```

Comment: does it fire when you add `console.log` above the `if` in the callback? It has to

Comment: Um, I think I found another bug. `selectedItem` is not set properly. Try my updated code from the answer

Comment: yeah it gets fired

Comment: Please try my updated code, does it work? If not, could you please post the result of the `console.log(errorCase, selected)`?

Comment: thanks for your time man I resolved it I simply removed the if statement and it works even without that selected variable

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to remove the if statement and it works

```
   document.querySelector("#optionList").addEventListener("change",function(e){
    document.querySelector(".error-case").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.querySelector(".optionList").classList.remove("error-red");
});
```